# Is any prime element irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> I have seen many proofs about a prime element is irreducible, but up to now I am thinking whether this result is true for any ring.

Recently, I got this proof:

Suppose that $a$ is prime, and that $a = bc$. Then certainly $a\mid bc$, so by definition of prime, $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$, say $a \mid b$.
If $b = ad$ then $b = bcd$, so $cd = 1$ and therefore $c$ is a unit. (Note that $b$ cannot be $0$,for
if so, $a = bc = 0$, which is not possible since $a$ is prime.) Similarly, if $a\mid c$ with $c = ad$ then $c = bcd$,  so $bd = 1$ and $b$ is a unit. Therefore $a$ is irreducible.

I think with the above proof we do not need the ring to be an integral domain. If this is the case then I will stop doubting, else, I am still in it.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: The proof is incorrect if the ring is not a domain because $b=bcd$ does not imply $1=cd$, even if you assume $b\neq 0$.

Comment: If I get you Georges, primes are irreducible only in a domain.

Comment: It is worse than that, Hassan: I don't even think that the notion "irreducible" is a good one in rings with zero-divisors. On the other hand the notion of prime element, with the definition you used in your post, seems to me quite reasonable, even  in a ring which isn't a domain. Of course this is somewhat subjective, but I have the feeling that I'm expressing a rather widely held consensus among algebraists.

Comment: Notes, In ring $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, we have $(b,0) = (b,0)(1,c)(1,d)$, obviously $(1,c)(1,d) \ne \mathbf 1$

Comment: $b=bcd \Rightarrow b(cd-1) = 0 \Rightarrow b=0 \text{ or } cd=1$ Here requires $R$ is a domain

Comment: The statement holds only for an ID with unity, and not all ID's. Is that a correct conclusion?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149078/173147

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Notice that your proof assumes that $\rm\: b\ne 0\ \Rightarrow\ b\:$ is cancellable, so it fails if $\rm\:b\:$ is a zero-divisor. Factorization theory is more complicated in non-domains. Basic notions such as *associate* and *irreducible* bifurcate into a few inequivalent notions. See for example

[When are Associates Unit Multiples?](https://doi.org/10.1216/rmjm/1181069828)
D.D. Anderson, M. Axtell, S.J. Forman, and Joe Stickles.
Rocky Mountain J. Math. Volume 34, Number 3 (2004), 811-828.

[Factorization in Commutative Rings with Zero-divisors.](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1181072068)
D.D. Anderson, Silvia Valdes-Leon.
Rocky Mountain J. Math. Volume 28, Number 2 (1996), 439-480

Comment: Interesting papers mentioned. Thanks

Comment: If i could i would give + 100 :)

Comment: When I try to download the PDFs from those links, I get 'Invalid or corrupted PDF file' , in both cases.

Comment: @evaristegd Both work fine for me.

Comment: You're right. It was probably a problem related to the fact that I was using Brave Browser.

Answer (score 12):

If you choose the definition of $a$ is irreducible if $a=bc$ implies that $(a)=(b)$ or $(a)=(c)$ then it is true actually.  For instance the proof is as follows:

Let $p\in R$ be a non-zero, non-unit.  Suppose $p=bc$.   We clearly have $b\mid p$ and $c \mid p$ since $b$ and $c$ are factors of $p$.  On the other hand, $1\cdot p=bc$ implies that $p \mid bc$ and $p$ being prime implies $p \mid b$ or $p \mid c$.  Thus $(p)=(b)$ or $(p)=(c)$ showing $p$ is irreducible by this definition.

Unfortunately, prime is quite different than any of the other possible definitions of irreducible when zero-divisors are present that I am familiar with.  The definition above is the weakest choice for irreducible that I am aware of.