# If $d_1 \mid d_2$ then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are associates

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why does it follow that if $d_1 = \gcd(a,b)$, $d_2 = \gcd(a,b)$ and $d_1\mid d_2$ then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are associates?

Comment: in which ring are you working? namely, where do $a,b$ come from? (are they integers or what?)

Comment: They are in an integral domain D

Comment: Any two gcds $d_1,d_2$ of $a,b$ are associate (since $d_1\mid d_2$ and $d_2\mid d_1$, both following from the universal property of the gcd). However if you are prescribing some sort of well-defined gcd function and define $d_1$ and $d_2$ to both be gcd(a,b), then not only are $d_1,d_2$ associate they are equal by definition. The wording seems strange to me.

Answer (score 3):

In a commutative ring, if $d=gcd(a,b)$ and $e$ divides both $a$ and $b$ then, by definition, $e$ divides $d$. Now, given that $d_1=gcd(a,b)$ and $d_2=gcd(a,b)$ it follows that $d_1$ divides $d_2$ (by taking $e=d_2$) and it also follows that $d_2$ divides $d_1$ (by taking $e=d_1$), so that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are associates (so that the extra condition that $d_1$ divides $d_2$ is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused if $d_1$ divides $d_2$ and $d_2$ divides $d_1$ then $d_1 = d_2$ but this theorem says that gcd is not unique . Could you clarify that?

Comment: In an arbitrary ring, $x$ may divide $y$ and $y$ may divide $x$ without them being equal. They are then called companions. For an extreme example, in a field any two non-zero elements are companions.

Comment: @user61835 gcd is unique up to multiplication by a unit. For example, the gcd in $\mathbb{Z}$ is determined up to sign, and we normally take it to be the positive choice by convention. In other rings, there may not be so natural a choice.

Comment: In an arbitrary ring (even with unit) not any two companions defer by a unit (this does hold in an integral domain).

Comment: Remark that in non-domains the notion of *associate*, *irreducible* etc bifurcate into motley inequivalent notions, e.g. see the papers [cited here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/69538/23500) So perhaps it would be better to write "domain" instead of "ring".