# In a integral domain every prime element is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to understand a proof of [Hungerford's book](http://libgen.org/get?nametype=orig&md5=3CF13F219E5121470C6D659A9AB9F46C) which says that in a integral domain every prime element is irreducible:

[image]

I didn't understand why this implication $p=ab\implies p|a$ or $p|b$, is not the contrary $p=ab\implies a|p$ and $b|p$ ?

I'm a little confused

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $p = ab$, then in particular $p$ *divides* $ab$, because $ab = p \cdot 1$. Since $p$ is prime, it has to divide either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Of course,thank you very much for your help

Comment: @user74141, you're welcome.

Comment: @user74141 One can make the inference prime $\,\Rightarrow\,$ irreducible more clear by using an alternative definition of irreducible - see my answer.

Comment: I don't understand the part, 1=xb hence b=1 (or b is a unit), how does it tie together, can you help?

Comment: The statement holds only for an ID with unity, and not all ID's. Is that right?

Comment: @utkarshk5, I subscribe to the persuasion that integral domains are defined to have a unity. I know some authors prefer otherwise - should have mentioned my preference explicitly.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti thank you for the prompt response; it clears it up.

Answer (score 8):

Prime $\Rightarrow$ irreducible [is obvious](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4399/242) if we employ a definition of irreducible in [associate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/405833/78535) (vs. $\rm\color{#0a0}{unit}$) form. Then $\,\color{#c00}{ p=ab\,\Rightarrow\,  p\mid ab}\,$ immediately yields the sought inference, as follows.

**Theorem** $\ \ $ In the following, $\,\ (1)\,\Rightarrow\,(2)\!\iff\! (3)$

$(1)\ \ \ \color{#c00}{p\ \mid\ ab}\  \Rightarrow\  p\:|\:a\ \ {\rm or}\ \ p\:|\:b\quad$ [Definition of $\:p\:$ is prime]

$(2)\ \ \ \color{#c00}{p=ab}\ \Rightarrow\ p\:|\:a\ \ {\rm or}\ \ p\:|\:b\quad$ [Definition of $\:p\:$ is irreducible, in [associate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/405833/78535) form]

$(3)\ \ \ p=ab\ \Rightarrow\ a\:|\:1\ \ {\rm or}\ \ b\:|\:1\quad$ [Definition of $\:p\:$ is  irreducible, in $\rm\color{#0a0}{unit}$ form]

**Proof** $\ \ \ (1\Rightarrow 2)\,\ \ \ \color{#c00}{p = ab\, \Rightarrow\, p\mid ab}\,\stackrel{(1)}\Rightarrow\,p\mid a\:$ or $\:p\mid b.\ $ Hence prime $\Rightarrow$ irreducible.

$(2\!\!\iff\!\! 3)\ \ \ $ If $\:p = ab\:$ then $\:\dfrac{1}b = \dfrac{a}p\:$ so $\:p\:|\:a\iff b\:|\:1.\:$ Similarly $\:p\:|\:b\iff a\:|\:1.$

**Beware** that factorization theory is more complicated in non-domains. Basic notions such as associate and irreducible bifurcate into a few inequivalent notions. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69538/242) for more on that.

Answer (score 3):

I think the OP was asking why the first implication is there instead of the alternate implication he proposed. The answer is that the first implication is part of the *definition* of a prime. Look at the definition of prime that precedes the theorem in question in Hungerford: An element p of R is prime provided that: (i) p is a nonzero non unit; (ii) p|ab $\Rightarrow$ p|a or p|b.

Comment: The link for the book is not working, can i ask exactly what book this was and the page number of the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $(p) \subset R$ be prime. We claim $p$ is irreducible.

Put

$$p = ab$$

And it’s enough to show either $a$ or $b$ is a unit. It’s clear that

$$ab \in (p)$$

But $(p)$ is prime so $a \in (p)$ or $b \in (p)$. So without any loss of generality suppose that $a \in (p)$ then there exists an $r \in R$ such that

$$a=pr \Rightarrow p = prb$$

By cancellation we conclude $rb=1$ thus $b$ is a unit and $p$ is irreducible.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).