# Are distinct irreducible monic polynomials relatively prime?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to prove the statement:

> Any two distinct irreducible monic polynomials are
> relatively prime (coprime).

**Attempt:** Let $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$ be two distinct irreducible polynomials. Assume they are not relatively prime. Then there exists a polynomial, $h(x)$, such that

> $\phi_1(x) = h(x)h'(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \phi_2(x) = h(x)h''(x) $,

for polynomials $h'(x)$ and $h''(x)$ of appropriate degree. But this implies that $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$ can be expressed as a product of two polynomials. Hence, they can't be irreducible.

**Comment:** I'm not too sure if the proof is correct. I haven't seemed to have used the conditions that the polynomials are both distinct and monic. What am I doing wrong?

I don't have much background in abstract algebra. I came across this thereom in an appendix on polynomials in a book on liner algebra, so I am going through it to cover the unit on minimal polynomials.

Comment: The appendix doesn't commit to a field. I think it is implicit the fields is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, as is the case with most linear algebra books.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that constants count as polynomials - so, for example, $x^2 + 2x + 2$ can be written as $(x^2 + 2x + 2) \cdot 1$. Thus, $x^2 + 2x + 2$ and $2x^2 + 4x + 4$ aren't relatively prime, because $2x^2 + 4x + 4 = (x^2 + 2x + 2) \cdot 2$. That's where the monic condition comes in.

The distinct condition comes from the fact that if $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are not distinct, then $\phi_2 = \phi_1 \cdot 1$.

Comment: So as of yet, my proof is incomplete; but the part of it that it stated is right?

Comment: @JunaidAftab Well, almost. The statement "$\phi_1(x)$ cannot be expressed as the product of two polynomials" is false; it can't be expressed as the product of two *nonconstant* polynomials. So your proof so far just shows that either $h(x)$ is a constant or both $h'(x)$ and $h''(x)$ are.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,p,q\,$ are irreducible then nonunit $\,d\mid p,q\,\Rightarrow\, up = d = vq\ $ for units (invertibles) $u,v,\,$ so $\, q = v^{-1}u p,\,$ so comparing lead coef's using $\,p,q\,$ monic yields $\,v^{-1}u = 1,\,$ hence $\,q = p$.

**Remark** $ $ The sketched proof (implicitly) uses the fact that only constants can be units, which need not hold true in rings that are not integral domains, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19145/242) Generally factorization theory is more complicated in non-domains, e.g. $\rm\:x = (3+2x)(2-3x)\in \Bbb Z_6[x].\:$ Basic notions such as *associate* and *irreducible* bifurcate into a few inequivalent notions, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1148088/242)