# Units, Prime Elements and Irreducible elements for polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Are there any general steps or things to look out for when identifying the unit elements, irreducible elements and prime elements in ring of polynomials e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$, $\mathbb{C}[x]$, $\mathbb{R}[x]$, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

It seems a little tricky.

Thank you.

Comment: It gets tricky, yes!

Comment: Be aware that there in non-domains the notions of "associate" and "irreducible" bifurcate into a few inequivalent notions, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2142826/242), so it is essential to state which definition one is using.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is tricky. The other three are well-known
First of all units can only be from polynomials that are constants.

For irreducible polynomials over $\mathbf Q$ one has well-known Eisenstein theorem that guarantees one in each degree (alternately simpler result about the integers: like $\sqrt[n]p$ is irrational for any prime number shows that the polynomial $X^n-p$ is irreducible for every $n$.)

For  complex numbers we use Liouville's theorem and conclude that all polynomials have roots, allowing us to conclude that irreducible ones have to be  of degree 1. From this one can conclude that irreducible real polynomials have to be either in degree 1 or 2, and not higher. 
Primes and irreducibles are the same in them is a consequence of the fact that this is a PID.