# Relationship between primes, irreducibles and UFDs and vacuously true

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-fields, unique-factorization-domains

My understanding is that irreducible elements cannot be written as the product of two non-units.
Therefore, in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, the ring/field of integers modulo 7, because every nonzero element is a unit, every element must be irreducible.

My understanding is that an element $p \in \mathbb{Z}_7$ is prime iff:
$$p|ab \Rightarrow p|a \text{ or } p|b$$
In $\mathbb{Z}_7$, every element is prime because p|a is true of any nonzero elements $a,b,p \in \mathbb{Z}_7$

Is my explanation true?

Similarly, this would work for any finite field.

Do these constitute unique factorisation domains (UFDs)? Would it not be vacuously true, since there are no nonzero non-units that "every non zero non-unit *cannot* be written uniquely as the product of non-irreducible elements"? I guess I am looking for more intuition as to why the integers modulo p, where p is prime, constitute a UFD given that all nonzero elements are both irreducible and prime.

Also: I tried to find an example of a non-UFD. I tried $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and concluded that it is NOT a UFD because you can't write elements like 2,3,4 (which are nonzero non-units) as the product of irreducibles (the irreducibles in this set being 1 and 5) at all. Is this true? Are there examples of a set of integers modulo n that is NOT a UFD because there are 2 or more ways to write a number as the product of irreducible elements, or do most/all rings that are not UFDs just have elements that can't be written *at all* as the product of irreducibles? Sorry for long question - just very interested!

Comment: $\Bbb Z_6$ is not even an integral domain. For an interesting example of a non-UFD consider $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the question poorly. I meant to say are there any examples of non-UFDs amongst the sets of integers modulo n, in which you can write an element in more than one way as the product of irreducible elements. I want to find these examples as I want to teach someone about this who doesn't know about complex numbers.

Comment: A finite integral domain is necessarily a field.

Comment: Is that because if "ab=ac and a nonzero implies b=c" means that a must be invertible?

Comment: Generally factorization theory is *more complicated* in non-domains, e.g. $\rm\:x = (3+2x)(2-3x)\in \Bbb Z_6[x].\:$ Basic notions such as *associate* and *irreducible* bifurcate into a few inequivalent notions, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1148088/242)