# Proof of that in an integral domain, every prime element is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I would like to prove that in an integral domain $R$, every prime element $p$ is irreducible. I understand the case where $p = ab$ but the textbooks I have read do not address the case where $p \neq ab$, i.e.,$px = ab$.

I was wondering why they do not discuss the case where $px = ab$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to examine the case $p\neq ab$.

In order to prove every prime element $p$ is irreducible you have to show IF $p=ab$, then $a$ or $b$ is an unit (see the definition of irreducible element).

However, if we have $p\neq ab$? It doesn't matter, we don't care, what matters to us is just the case whenever $p=ab$.

Comment: By $p \neq ab$, I am referring to the case where $px = ab$.

Comment: @EdwardPoon Why do you like to analyse this case? you want to prove that $p$ is irreducible. If you prove the case for $px=ab$, you are proving $px$ is irreducible, instead of $p$.

Comment: If i recall correctly, the definition of a non-zero and non-unit element $p$ is prime if $p | ab \implies p | a$ or $p | b$ and $p | ab \implies px = ab$ for some $x \in R$.

Comment: @EdwardPoon yes, you are right. However, you want to prove that $p$ is irreducible. You already know that $p$ is prime.

Comment: Right, you are correct.

Comment: @EdwardPoon you have to use the fact $p$ is prime in the proof, but what you want to prove is $p$ is irreducible and to prove this you have to prove if $p=ab$, then $a$ or $b$ is unit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be an integral domain, if $p \in R$ is prime, then $p$ is irreducible.

Put

$$p=ab.$$

It suffices to show $a$ or $b$ is a unit. As $ab \in (p)$ and $(p)$ is prime, either $a \in (p)$ or $b \in (p)$. So WLOG suppose $a \in (p)$ then $a=pr$ for some $r \in R$ and thus

\begin{align}
p&=ab\\
&=rpb
\end{align}

And since were in an integral domain this imples $rb=1$ thus $b$ is a unit and $p$ is irreducible.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your [prior answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4706445/242), and please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score -1):

Proof:
suppose P is a prime element of an integral domain R, and p=ab
we know that, P|P => P|ab => P|a or P|b
              P|a and p=ab or a|P => a is unit 
similarly P|b and p=ab ir b|p => b is unit,
so either a is a unit or b is a unit, hence p must be irreducible element,

Comment: It would help to typeset your solution using MathJax. See this [introduction](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).