# Is $\sqrt{-5}$ the only prime in $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I am aware that $\sqrt{-5}$ is both prime and irreducible in  $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{-5}]$ . And that $2, 3 $ etc., are irreducible but not prime. My question is are there other prime elements in  $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{-5}]$?
Thanks for the response.

Comment: Integer primes $p\equiv 11,13,17,19\pmod {20}$ are prime here as well. These are the primes where $-5$ is not a quadratic residue.

Comment: Others are $6+\sqrt{-5},$ since it's norm is $41.$

Comment: Why do you say "both prime and irreducible"? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405759 Besides, [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) (mainly: show your attempts to solve your question).

Comment: Acknowledged, will follow the guide

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to understand what $\oplus$ stands for.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you please elaborate?

Comment: No, because you haven't told me what confuses you in my comment. Be specific. @PhalakshaCG

Comment: Why have you taken 20 in the mod. And does "-5 is not a quadratic residue" mean -5 not ≡ n^2 mod p ?