# Unique factorization question

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, unique-factorization-domains

Deciding if a ring $R$ has unique factorization or not is only considered if the ring $R$ has no zero-divisors.

The question is why ?

USUALLY we consider factorization up to units.
If - for instance - we consider factorization up to units and zero-divisors we can extend the concept of Unique factorization to rings with zero-divisors.

Also we could consider Unique factorization of group rings ( with or without zero-divisors ).

Comment: Because factorization theory is much more complicated in non-domains, e.g. basic notions like associate, irreducible, etc. bifurcate into many inequivalent notions. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/69538/242) for some introductory expositions.

Comment: I understand it is more complicated, but that is not a good reason imho. But thanks for the intresting reply. +1