# Specific elements of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm studying Ring Theory and I have 3 questions, if could be nice to hear your comments about that.

1) I would like to find a primer element which is not irreductible.
We said that $a$ is irreductible iff $a \in A - (A^{\times} \cup \{0\})$ and
$$
\forall (b,c) \in A, a = bc \Rightarrow b \in A^{\times} \text{ or } c \in A^{\times}
$$
If the ring $R$ is a integral domain then primer => irreductible.
We said that $a$ is a primer element iif $a \in A - (A^{\times} \cup \{0\})$ and 
$$
\forall b,c \in A, a|bc \Rightarrow a|b \text{ or } a|c
$$

2) I'm trying to find the primer and the irreductible element of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, but I can just study exemples when $n$ is not a prime. Do you know how to study it in general ?

Thanks for your help and regards.

Comment: They are called “primes” not primers. To find and example of a prime element that is not irreducible consider $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and the prime element $2=2\times{}4$.

Comment: Where did you read the second statement?

Comment: Okay I will edit.

Comment: I read it on internet but I think I didn't really understand the text so I deleted my question for the moment ^^.

Comment: You need to say which definition of irreducible you are using since there is not any standard denotation of irreducible and associate in general rings - see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69538/242) The paper(s) linked there discuss this and related matters at length.

Comment: I edited with a definition of what I called irreductible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is *Μάρκος Καραμέρης*'s answer:

> To find and example of a prime element that is not irreducible consider $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and the prime element $2=2×4$.

Elements that you call irreducible will be omnipresent in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ($p$ a prime) since this is a field, and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}-(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times \cup \{0\} )=\varnothing$.